# Get Data Using PHP: Pull data

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am a newbie to PHP programming. I am trying to get my code to work correctly.
I work as a teacher and I am trying to make a database to help keep track of my students damaged laptops. I have two different webpages index.php and connect.php (setups connection to my 'sterling' database. I would like to be able to enter a student’s ID# and have the student’s information such as:
First Name / Last Name / Student ID / Grade / Pic to populate on the page. I guess it is similar to the vlookup in excel that will pull the student data from the ‘students’ table. I haven’t entered any pictures in the database as of yet, but that will be later on. I have already looked at tutorials online but I cannot seem to get what I saw work with my programming. Any help is very much appreciated.

**index.php**

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
<style>
form {font-family: fantasy !important; position:fixed; top:60%; left:25%;}
label{display:inline-block;width: 400px; margin-bottom: 50px; font-size: 30px; color: green;}
input[type=text] {width: 50%; font-size: 220%; color: black; box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid #555; background-color: white; -webkit-transition: 0.5s; transition: 0.5s; outline: none;}

input[type=text]:focus {border: 3px solid #F2694C; background-color: #F2694C; background-image: url('/img/searchicon.png'); background-position: 330px 10px; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
input[type=submit]:focus {top: 30px;}
h1 {font-family: century gothic; text-align: center; font-size: 100px; color: red; position: relative; top: 50px}
img {position: relative; top: -50px; left: 870px;}
</style>


<title>Student Damage Report</title>
</head>
<body background="/img/back.jpg">
<h1>STUDENT DAMAGE REPORT</h1>

<br><br><br>

<img src="/img/id.png" />
<form method="post" action="connect.php">
<label>Please Enter Student ID# </label><input type="text" name="student_id" />
<br>

<center>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>


 </center>


</body>
</html>
```

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uobmg.jpg)

**Update**
Here is the php code that I am using. This is from my Connect.php.

```
<?php
$connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','username','','sterling');
$db = mysqli_select_db("sterling", $connection); // Selecting Database


if(mysqli_connect_errno($connection))
{
        echo 'Failed to connect';
}



//MySQL Query to read data
$query = mysqli_query("select * from students", $connection);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
echo "<b>{$row['first_name']}</b>";
echo "<br />";
}


?>


Database Definition
 Database: `sterling`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `damage`
--

CREATE TABLE `damage` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` text NOT NULL,
  `last_name` text NOT NULL,
  `department` text NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(320) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `employee`
--

CREATE TABLE `employee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `employee`
--

INSERT INTO `employee` (`id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `email`) VALUES
(12345, 'Henry Smith', '300', ''),
(12345, 'James', 'Maackey', 'james_mackey@gmail.com');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `students`
--

CREATE TABLE `students` (
  `FIRST_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STUDENT_ID` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `GRADE` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ASSET` varchar(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SERIAL` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PIC` blob
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `students`
--

INSERT INTO `students` (`FIRST_NAME`, `LAST_NAME`, `STUDENT_ID`, `GRADE`, `ASSET`, `SERIAL`, `PIC`) VALUES
('James', 'Smith', 123456, 9, '126785', 90210, NULL),
('Tim', 'Robbins', 789654, 12, '456985', 3578951, NULL);

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `damage`
--
ALTER TABLE `damage`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- Indexes for table `students`
--
ALTER TABLE `students`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`STUDENT_ID`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `damage`
--
ALTER TABLE `damage`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

**Here is the PIC**
 [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo1Oo.jpg)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
<style>
form {font-family: fantasy !important; position:fixed; top:60%; left:25%;}
label{display:inline-block;width: 400px; margin-bottom: 50px; font-size: 30px; color: green;}
input[type=text] {width: 50%; font-size: 220%; color: black; box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 3px solid #555; background-color: white; -webkit-transition: 0.5s; transition: 0.5s; outline: none;}

input[type=text]:focus {border: 3px solid #F2694C; background-color: #F2694C; background-image: url('/img/searchicon.png'); background-position: 330px 10px; background-repeat: no-repeat;}
input[type=submit]:focus {top: 30px;}
h1 {font-family: century gothic; text-align: center; font-size: 100px; color: red; position: relative; top: 50px}
img {position: relative; top: -50px; left: 870px;}
</style>


<title>Student Damage Report</title>
</head>
<body background="/img/back.jpg">
<h1>STUDENT DAMAGE REPORT</h1>

<br><br><br>

<img src="/img/id.png" />
<form method="post" action="index.php"
<label>Please Enter Student ID# </label><input type="text" name="student_id" />
<br>

<center>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
</form>






 </center>




 <?php
$pdo = null;
$studentId = $_POST['student_id'] ?? null; // handle case where we don't get a student id
try {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db = 'sterling';
    $dsn = "mysql:dbname={$db};host={$host}";
    $user = 'user';
    $pass = '';
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // Connection failed
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

// if we have a student id
if ( $studentId ) {
    // add a where clause
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `studentId` = ?';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $studentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $student = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} else {
    $student = null;
}
?>

<?php if ( $student ) :?>
<div>

<div>Student Id <?= $student['studentId']?></div>
<div>First Name <?= $student['first_name']?></div>

</div>

<?php else : ?>
    <div>Student <?= $studentId ?> not found</div>
<?php endif?>











</body>










</html>
```

Comment: Why did you write everything in **Bold**? And where is your PHP code?

Comment: Sorry about that, I changed it. I was not sure how to tie the PHP code needed to pull the data to what I have already.

Comment: Currently you have nothing except HTML code, this won't do the data pulling you want, you need to try and write a PHP code and post the problems you face so we can help you, you have to try something.

Comment: I would not use `#` in column names, just looks weird, even if it works.

Comment: I have updated my code and added the PHP. I also removed the #'s from my database column Names

Comment: You are mixing `mysqli` and `mysql` function calls. `mysql` is obsolete. Don't use it.

Comment: Add your table definition to your question.

Comment: mysqli_query not mysql_query. Likewise mysqli_fetch_array not mysql_fetch_array. Be careful not to confuse / mix the two libraries, especially as the older mysql_ library is dead

Comment: A picture of your database is nice, but an actual CREATE TABLE statement is way better so I can try my solution before entering it.

Comment: I have updated it with the SQL for the entire database.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly implementing all your requirements. This is a working example which you can use to get your solution working.

Assuming the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `studentId` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`studentId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With this data:

```
INSERT INTO `student` (`studentId`, `first_name`, `last_name`)
VALUES
(1, 'Spencer', 'Emison'),
(2, 'Brian', 'Caldwell'),
(3, 'Jamie', 'Scott');
```

Here is code to lookup a student by id based on entering the student id on the form. I am using PDO because I think it leads to cleaner code.

```
<?php
$pdo = null;
$studentId = $_POST['student_id'] ?? null; // handle case where we don't get a student id
try {
    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $db = 'sss';
    $dsn = "mysql:dbname={$db};host={$host}";
    $user = 'app';
    $pass = 'aaaa';
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // Connection failed
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

// if we have a student id
if ( $studentId ) {
    $isSearch = true;
    // add a where clause
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `student` WHERE `studentId` = ?';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $studentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $student = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

} else {
    $student = null;
    $isSearch = false;
}
?>

<?php if ( $student ) :?>
<div>

<div>Student Id <?= $student['studentId']?></div>
<div>First Name <?= $student['first_name']?></div>

</div>
<?php elseif ( $isSearch ) : ?>
    <div>Student <?= $studentId ?> not found</div>
<?php endif?>
```

Here is how to list all students:

```
<div><h2>All Students</h2></div>
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `student` ';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
    <div><?=$row['studentId']?>  <?=$row['first_name']?></div>
<?php endwhile?>
```

If you need PHP Info :

info.php

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Then go to http://localhost/info.php

Comment: So I created the 'student' database using your SQL, which I really appreciate. When I run my application, it only states, "could not find driver." I am not sure why it is saying that.

Comment: Use `php -m` on the command line and make sure you have the PDO PHP extension.

Comment: OK.. I checked the PHP settings and the PHP PDO Mysql extension was disabled. I enabled it, and now I am getting, " SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'student'" which is weird since this is the correct DB.

Comment: Isn't your database named `sterling`?

Comment: WOW what a DOH!! moment... I was confusing it with the table for some reason. You are awesome!!!! So appreciate your help and patience

Comment: Can I ask one last question. I combined the Connect.php page inside of my index.php so that I could show the output of the names of the students directly on the main web page. When I run it,  it seems to jump directly to the "Student is not found" statement. I thought playing with the code I could add {} or () to see if that would make a difference. It did not. I also changed the "<form method="post" action="index.php" to itself, but with no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a code snippet in the answer that shows how to get the list of all students.

Comment: No I think I did not explain it correctly. I am not trying to display all of the students. Just the one I am looking for. When I load the page it automatically brings up the "Student is not found" statement. I have added a picture.

Comment: You combined the two files into one file? If you want to do that, you need to handle the situation where the page comes up initially and not see that as an attempt to find a student.